# How to redirect to another page when user click the anchor tag using Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want redirect to another page when user click the link using jquery, not using href=""

I tried the below code. But it doesn't work

```
$('.list-of-link').on('click', 'a', function () {
    alert($(this).html());
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
})
```

alert is working. But the redirect or replace is not working.

```
<div class="list-of-link">         
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">jjj</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">jassom</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">filetest</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">testsucces</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">faisal</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">tajul</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">description</a><br>
    <a class="SavedLink" href="">description1</a><br>
</div>
```

**Update**

> those links has been done by ajax. by following code:

```
var UserID=$('#hiddenSessionUserID').val()
$.ajax({
    url: 'SavedReports.aspx/getSavedReportName',
    method: 'post',
    contentType: 'application/json',
    data: '{userID:"' + UserID + '"}',
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        if (data.d !== 'No Reports') {
            //alert("success" + data.d);
            var fullData = data.d;

            var splitData = fullData.split('$$$');

            for (var i = 0; i < splitData.length; i++) {
                var oneLinkData = splitData[i];

                var splitoneLinkData = oneLinkData.split('###');
                //alert(splitoneLinkData[0] + "   " + splitoneLinkData[1]);
                $(".list-of-link").append('<a class="SavedLink" href="" >' + splitoneLinkData[1] + '</a><br/>');
            }
        }
    },
    error: function (error) {
        alert('Please Call Administrator');
    }
})
```

Comment: Code should work, Nothing wrong on the above code, Are you getting an alert?

Comment: Don't use global 'a' tag, define a class.

Comment: better to use  `window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");`

Comment: Do you get an error in the console?

Comment: Why do you want to remove some functionality that works perfectly fine in every browser, with or without javascript?

Comment: @Deepaksharma I tried. it doesn't work

Comment: @j08691 I didn't get any error in console as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can update `href=""` to `href=";"` or  `href="javascript:;"`

Answer (score 1):

Specify # in your anchor href and the rest of your code executes as expected:

```
    <a class="SavedLink" href="#">jjj</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one :

```
$('.list-of-link').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();// add this line
    alert($(this).html());
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
})
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to [prevent the default action](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/preventDefault) like so

```
$('.list-of-link').on('click', 'a', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    alert($(this).html());
    window.location.replace("http://stackoverflow.com");
})
```

This stops the anchor tag doing what it's meant to do and navigating using the href attribute.
If you don't want to do this in JS you can also just remove the href attributes from your HTML

**EDIT: Just saw your extra code.**

You can change

```
$(".list-of-link").append('<a class="SavedLink" href="" >' + splitoneLinkData[1] + '</a><br/>');
```

to

```
$(".list-of-link").append('<a class="SavedLink">' + splitoneLinkData[1] + '</a><br/>');
```

Comment: if I add the `e.preventDefault();` even the alert box is not working. I tried after I move to the last line of function as well

Comment: @mohamedfaiz did you add `e` in the function parameter?

Answer (score -1):

You could use:

```
$('.list-of-link').on('click', 'a', function () {
    window.location.href = "http://stackoverflow.com";})
```